# how to hide/show a specific view inside the custom tableview cell when button click inside the same cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, row-height

- I have a `table view` with (ex : 20 rows). and I have used a `custom table view cell` with this `table view`.
- inside this `table view cell`, there are few `labels`, one `button` and a `hidden view (UIView)`.
- I have written `button` `action` for `hide/show` the `hidden view` inside the `custom table view cell class`.it works fine.but it affect to other `rows` in the table view. that means, when I tap the button in first row, then the hidden view show, and it can see in some other rows in the table view when `scroll down`.
- At the same time (when `hide/show`), I want to `increase` and `decrease` the row height (only clicked row/cell) . what is going wrong. below is my codes and some screen shots to get an idea.

[image: this is the first row when click in expand button]

[image: at the same time when I scroll, this is the look of other rows/cell, the show the hidden view without clicking on expand button]

**note : cell expand/increase it self when click on expand button in each cell.**

this is how I `hide` and `show` the `hidden view`, inside the `custom table view cell` class.

```
- (IBAction)hideshow:(id)sender {
    BOOL ishidden = self.insideCollectionView.hidden;
    if(ishidden == true)
    {
        self.insideCollectionView.hidden = false;
    }
    else
    {
        self.insideCollectionView.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

what is going wrong, hope your help with this.

**Advance : it is great if there is a way to do both hide/show and expand(increase the row height) of the cell when click on expand button for each cell.**

Comment: Why aren't you using a single `UICollectionView` with the `expand` option in `CollectionViewHeaders`? Less complex code, and for hiding/expanding you could implement the `numberOfCellsInRow` method to set the row `count` to `0` accordingly, and even animate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the suited solution for this by my self. thanx everyone who supported me.

Do the followings.

1. Create a `NSMutableArray` to hold `Which` `button` in `Which` `row`
   `clicked`.
2. Then when user click on the `Button` in `Custom table view cell`, check it that `index path` is `already` in the `mutable array`, if it is `already` inside it, then `romove` it ,otherwise add it.
3. Then in the `cellforrowatindexpath` method, check that `nsmutable array` and , check whether the `indexpath.row` is `exist` or `not`.
4. Finally, if it is `exists`, do not hide, else `hide` it, this works perfectly.

here is the implementation for the table view. `.m` file

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 25;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FirstTableViewCell *cells = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tvcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *theIndexpath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

//here check whether it is exists or not.
        if ([chekcme containsObject:theIndexpath])
        {
            cells.insideCollectionView.hidden = false;
        }
        else
        {
            cells.insideCollectionView.hidden = true;
        }



    [cells setColletionData:bbarray];

    [cells.expandMe addTarget:self action:@selector(runs:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//in here set the tag of the button to indexpath.row
    cells.expandMe.tag = indexPath.row;


    return cells;
}

//this is the action for the button inside the custom tableview cell.
- (IBAction)runs:(UIButton *)sender{

    NSString *myob = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li", (long)sender.tag];
    NSLog(@"%@",myob);

    if ([chekcme containsObject:myob]) {
        [chekcme removeObject:myob];
    }
    else
    {
        [chekcme addObject:myob];
    }


    NSLog(@"%@", chekcme);

//keep in mind to reload the table view here.
    [self.maintableView reloadData];
}
```

> **note : checkme is NSMutableArray to holds the objects clicked by the user.**

Answer (score 0):

I will need to see the code in your tableview data source methods, but i think following can solve your issues:

Issue #1: I am assuming your are using deque for your cell, this is causing the cell to be reused when you scroll. I will suggest you to maintain the state of your each cell (eg: isExpanded) and configure cell accordingly in cellForRowAtIndex:

Issue #2: Use the same 'IsExpanded' in heightForRowAtIndex: and call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths: on the table for your cell when state is changed for 'IsExpanded'

Answer (score 0):

you have need to reload all table instead of single cell
 you can use below code

```
 tbl_name .beginUpdates(
 tbl_name .endUpdates()
```

**Update**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   if indexPath.row == userselectedrow // save selectecd cell index  if you want to only one cell expand otherwise save selected row in array and compare to here
        {
             return incrementheight // increment row height here
        }
        else
        {
          return decrementheight // decrement row height
        }      

    }

- (IBAction)hideshow:(UIButton*)sender {
 CGPoint point11=[sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:tbl_calender];
   NSIndexPath index_pathGlobal =[tbl_calender indexPathForRowAtPoint:point11]; // save index_pathGlobal
}
```

hope this will be help you

Comment: how to use it, I do not no how to use it and where to use it.

Comment: in your button click action and increase height of row which cell you want expand and other row height which want to decrease

Comment: can you bit explain with necessary code will appreciate. thanx in advance

Comment: how can I save the selected row, because I want to do this for button click inside the cell, not in did select row at index path, because I want to navigate to another controller when user click on the row.

Comment: check updates answer get indexpath using button click

Answer (score 0):

You should set the status about the view initially in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Hope it will help you.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// here you have to maintain the status about the current cell. whether it is hidden or not.
    cell.insideCollectionView.hidden = status;
    }
```

Comment: how you call it with `self`, because the `insideCollectionView` is inside my `custom table view cell`,

Comment: could you please explain bit with code will be appreciate.

Comment: What I meant to say is, in cellForRowAtIndexPath we have the reference of the cell right? with that you can control the hiding.

Answer (score 0):

That the button affects several `rows` is because you store the `BOOL` in the `collectionView` in the `cell`.

When the `cell` is reused for another `row`, that `cell` will be `hidden/shown` based on the status of the `row` it was previously used for. As has already been suggested you need to store this `state` for each and every one of your `rows` and set it accordingly when the `cell` is prepared by the `dataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

I,am doing the same thing like:
In didSelect

```
  switch selectedIndexPath {
    case nil:
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
    }
  tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

And at row height

```
if selectedIndexPath != nil {
        if selectedIndexPath == indexPath {
            return estimatedHeight
        }
    }
    return 44
```

The selectedIndexPath is a property of NSIndexPath.
Hope this may help you.

Comment: yep, this can do if I want to do with did select row at index path, but I want to do it when button click, because I want to use did select row at index path to navigate to another view.

Comment: yes, you perform with button too, by setting tag to them.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**:- Assume that you are showing data in rows like label value, button and hidden view.Add one parameter in your array ex. **isViewNeedToShow**, By default fill that value **FALSE**.

**Step 2**:- After that in your button action your are passing indexPath.row as tag value in cell for row at index path, So on button action change the array vale parameter  **isViewNeedToShow  == TRUE**, and reload the section of table view. For ex:-

```
Item *tempItem              = yourArray[sender.tag];
tempItem. isViewNeedToShow  = tempItem. isViewNeedToShow ? FALSE : TRUE;

**For particular row update** :- 

 [yourTableView beginUpdates];
 [yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[sender.tag, 0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
 [yourTableView endUpdates];
```

**Step 3**:- If you want to expand table cell you have to calculate height of row that contains the items like view, label etc.

```
Or if you are using auto layouts in your project use UI Table View Delegate Methods

    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
```

**I hopes your problem would be resolved.**