# Showing and hiding a view only on a specific cell of a table view

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a table view with custom cells. They are quite tall, so only one cell is completely visible on the screen and maybe, depending on the position of that cell, the top 25% of the second one. These cells represent dummy items, which have names. Inside of each cell there is a button. When tapped for the first time, it shows a small `UIView` inside the cell and adds the item to an array, and being tapped for the second time, hides it and removes the item. The part of adding and removing items works fine, however, there is a problem related to showing and hiding views because of the fact that cells are reused in a `UITableView`

When I add the view, for example, on the first cell, on the third or fourth cell (after the cell is reused) I can still see that view.

To prevent this I've tried to loop the array of items and check their names against each cell's name label's text. I know that this method is not very efficient (what if there are thousands of them?), but I've tried it anyway.

Here is the simple code for it (`checkedItems` is the array of items,  for which the view should be visible):

```
  if let cell = cell as? ItemTableViewCell {
        if cell.itemNameLabel.text != nil {

            for item in checkedItems {

                if cell.itemNameLabel.text == item.name {
                    cell.checkedView.isHidden = false

                } else {
                    cell.checkedView.isHidden = true

                }
            }
        }
```

This code works fine at a first glance, but after digging a bit deeper some issues show up. When I tap on the first cell to show the view, and then I tap on the second one to show the view on it, too, it works fine. However, when I tap, for example, on the first one and the third one, the view on the first cell disappears, but the item is still in the array. I suspect, that the reason is still the fact of cells being reused because, again, cells are quite big in their height so the first cell is not visible when the third one is. I've tried to use the code above inside `tableView(_:,cellForRow:)` and `tableView(_:,willDisplay:,forRowAt:)` methods but the result is the same.

So, here is the problem: I need to find an **EFFICIENT** way to check cells and show the view **ONLY** inside of those which items are in the `checkedItems` array.

**EDITED**
Here is how the cell looks with and without the view (the purple circle is the button, and the view is the orange one)

[image: The view is hidden]

[image: The view is visible]

And here is the code for the button:

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellDelegate: class {
func cellCheckButtonDidTapped(cell: ExampleTableViewCell)
 }
```

Inside the cell:

```
 @IBAction func checkButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    delegate?.cellCheckButtonDidTapped(cell: self)
}
```

Inside the view controller (NOTE: the code here just shows and hides the view. The purpose of the code is to show how the button interacts with the `table view`):

```
extension ItemCellsTableViewController: ItemTableViewCellDelegate {
func cellCheckButtonDidTapped(cell: ItemTableViewCell) {

    UIView.transition(with: cell.checkedView, duration: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        cell.checkedView.isHidden = !cell.checkedView.isHidden
    }, completion: nil)



}
```

**EDITED 2**

Here is the full code of `tableView(_ cellForRowAt:)` method (I've deleted the looping part from the question to make it clear what was the method initially doing). The `item` property on the cell just sets the name of the item (`itemNameLabel`'s `text`).

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:
        ItemTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ItemTableViewCell{
        cell.item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.delegate = self 

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

I've tried the solution, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489244/8803178), but this doesn't work for me.

If you have faced with such a problem and know how to solve it, I would appreciate your help and suggestions very much.

Comment: you want to show view in which cell you tapped and other cell view are hidden right?

Comment: @Kuldeep, yes. The View should be visible only in the cell in which the button is tapped `for the first time`. So, basically, I mean that showing and hiding the view in one cell, shouldn't affect other cells

Comment: do something like this: 1. add Tapped cell `indexPath` in array, than reload `UITableView` and in `cellForRow` method check `if([arrIndexpaths constainsobject:indexpath]) { show your view} else {hide your view}`.

Comment: @Kuldeep, the problem is, when I tap on a button, cell isn't tapped itself, so I can't get its `indexPath`

Comment: I updated my answer, please review it.

Comment: I added the method. As I mentioned in the question, I removed the looping part from it, so the initial structure of the method is clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167935/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-tigran-iskandaryan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Define Globally : `var arrIndexPaths = NSMutableArray()`

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = self.tblVW.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = String.init(format: "Row %d", indexPath.row)

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    if arrIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    return cell;
}


@IBAction func btnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    // IF YOU WANT TO SHOW SINGLE SELECTED VIEW AT A TIME THAN TRY THIS
    arrIndexPaths.removeAllObjects()
    arrIndexPaths.add(selectedIndexPath)
    self.tblVW.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: the problem is, when I tap on a button, the cell isn't tapped itself, so I can't get its indexPath

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan, I updated my answer, please review this.

Comment: I think this won't work either, because to send actions after the button is tapped I use delegation. The button is defined on the cell itself, so I can't get the `row` by sender's `tag`. Moreover, your answer assumes that the button on each cell should have different `tag` values, which can't be set because there could be 1000 cells or just 10.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan, can you please add some of your code and cell image so I can get better idea.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan, I don't understand, what code you write in `Cell` and what code in `ViewController`. Update with `cellForRow` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the state of your individual cells as part of the modeldata that lies behind every cell.

I assume that you have an array of model objects that you use when populating you tableview in `tableView(_:,cellForRow:)`. That model is populated from some backend service that gives you some JSON, which you then map to model objects once the view is loaded the first time.

If you add a property to your model objects indicating whether the cell has been pressed or not, you can use that when you populate your cell.

You should probably create a "wrapper object" containing your original JSON data and then a variable containing the state, lets call it `isHidden`. You can either use a `Bool` value or you can use an `enum` if you're up for it. Here is an example using just a `Bool`

```
struct MyWrappedModel {
    var yourJSONDataHere: YourModelType
    var isHidden = true

    init(yourJSONModel: YourModelType) {
        self.yourJSONDataHere = yourJSONModel
    }
}
```

In any case, when your cell is tapped (in `didSelectRow`) you would:

1. find the right `MyWrappedModel` object in your array of wrapped modeldata objects based on the indexpath
2. toggle the `isHidden` value on that
3. reload your affected row in the table view with `reloadRows(at:with:)`

In `tableView(_:,cellForRow:)` you can now check if `isHidden` and do some rendering based on that:

```
...//fetch the modelObject for the current IndexPath
cell.checkedView.isHidden = modelObject.isHidden
```

Futhermore, know that the method [`prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) exists on a `UITableViewCell`. This method is called when ever a cell is just about to be recycled. That means that you can use that as a last resort to "initialize" your table view cells before they are rendered. So in your case you could hide the `checkedView` as a default.

If you do this, you no longer have to use an array to keep track of which cells have been tapped. The modeldata it self knows what state it holds and is completely independent of cell positions and recycling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. That really could work, however I have a question: What if the data comes from JSON? I mean, if the JSON is made by me, I can add such a key and value pair to it and to my data struct, but what if I can't change the JSON structure?

Comment: But don't you map your JSON into model objects? I'm guessing you receive some JSON from a backend service somewhere and then you should map that into model objects, which you could then initialize with a default `isHidden` value of true. Have a look here to see how to map your JSON to model objects: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

Comment: Yes, it should and right now it does. But as far as I understand, your suggestion is to add a property (called let's say `isVisible`) to the model and then check against it. However, when I add this kind of property, the model isn't mapped correctly to JSON any more, so the data couldn't be decoded because there is no value associated with that key.

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan I've updated my answer, hope that helps. I'm not sure how you unwrap and store your JSON data, so maybe there is some dissimilarities between how we see things there?

Comment: Actually, this is a quite good suggestion. I'll give it a try and inform you about the results :)

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan keeping my fingers crossed for you :)

Comment: If you are using `Decodable` then you can simply include the `CodableKeys` `enum` to excuse the `isHidden` property from coding/decoding. Also, don't reload the whole table, just reload the affected row.